# Passing in **kwargs from Flex over PyAMF

Tags: python, remoting, pyamf, keyword-argument

Anyone know if it is easily possible to send `**kwargs` over PyAMF from `NetConnection.call()`? I would like it.

I could write a wrapper around the actual function and expose that and perform some parsing manually to determine the kwargs to pass in, but I don't want to do that. I will just use a normal argument list in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst ActionScript has the `*args` construct (`params ...`) there is no equivalent to `**kwargs`, although if you do need to send arbitrary named arguments, then you can always send a dict as a positional argument to the service. E.g.

```
def some_service_function(kwargs): # <- note the lack of **
    foo = kwargs.get('foo')
    bar = kwargs.get('bar')
```

And the calling ActionScript:

```
nc.call("some_service_function", {foo: "some", bar: "thing"})
```